# how to import excel file (XLSX) to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, import, import-from-excel

I have a set of data as input to be given to MongoDB in XLSX format. How am I supposed to import the Excel file as input to MongoDB?

Is there any plugin available to import xlsx files as input to MongoDB?

Comment: No. But you can use an xlsx module( https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-xlsx ) to read XLSX, then mongoose to addd the info to mongodb. Plus an intermediate code between those two steps to *prepare* data.

Comment: https://github.com/Moblox/mongo-xlsx does the intermediate work for you

Comment: @alandarev: Can node-xlsx read multiple sheets excel file?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You cannot import an XLSX file into MongoDB directly. However, what you can do with an Excel spreadsheet is save it as a CSV file, then use `mongoimport` to import it into MongoDB. You can find the documentation for `mongoimport` [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), but in any case, the command you need to run should look something like the following:

```
mongoimport --db myDb --collection myCollection --type csv --headerline --file /path/to/myfile.csv
```

In the command above, the `--headerline` flag indicates that the first line in your file contains the name of the fields. There are many other options you can use depending on your needs. These are highlighted in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

Answer (score 3):

I used **"fast-csv"** to upload csv onto mongoDB database.

**Sample Code**:

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");

csv.fromPath('./test.csv',{headers: true})
    .on("data", function(data){
       var details = new Details;
       details=data;
       details.save(function (saveErr, savedetail) {
             if (saveErr) {
                   console.log(saveErr)
             }
        });
    })
    .on("end", function(){
        console.log("done");
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [upload data of multiple sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWuMz.png) from one excel into mongodb at once using this code.
Your first row i.e "0" row will be consider as column title and rest data of that column.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
           DB db = mongoClient.getDB("yourdb_name");
           System.out.println("Connected to Database successfully");
           DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("your_collection name");
           System.out.println("Collection your_collection name selected successfully");

                DBCollection OR = db.getCollection("Input_Container");
                System.out.println("Collection Device_Details selected successfully");
                OR.drop();
                DBObject arg1 = null;
                //coll.update(query, update);
                DBCollection OR_UPLOAD = 
                db.createCollection("Input_Container", arg1);
                String path =" your file path";

                File myFile = new File(path);
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                int number=workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                  System.out.println("NumberOfSheets "+number);

                  for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
                  {
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                int col_value=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
                int row_num= sheet.getLastRowNum();
                System.out.println("row_num "+row_num);
                List<String> DBheader = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> Data = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int z=1;z<=row_num;z++){
                     DBheader.clear();
                     Data.clear();
                 for(int j=0;j<col_value;j++)
                {
                    if(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).toString()!=null || sheet.getRow(0)!=null)
                    {
                    String cel_value = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).toString();
                    DBheader.add(cel_value.trim());
                    }
                    else{
                        break;

                    }
                }
                for(int k=0;k<col_value;k++){
                    String data =" ";   
                    if(sheet.getRow(z).getCell(k)!=null)
                    {
                    data =  sheet.getRow(z).getCell(k).toString();
                    }
                    Data.add(data.trim());

                    }
                BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
                System.out.println("Data.size() "+Data.size());

                int l=0;
                for(String headers:DBheader)
                { 
                if(l>Data.size()){break;}
                    doc.append(headers, Data.get(l));
                    l++;
                 }
                OR_UPLOAD.insert(doc);
                }

            }System.out.println("File Upload Done");
                  mongoClient.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

mongoimport -d admin -c Mongocsv --type csv --file Mongocsv.csv --headerline

connected to: 127.0.0.1
imported 5 objects

mongo

> use admin
>   switched to db admin
>
> db.Mongocsv.find()

Answer (score 1):

There is a pymongo extention utilities package, one of the modules there does exactly this, imports an excel file to a mongo collection or a complete excel workbook to a mongo database.
You can find documentation and examples [here](http://miloncdn.appspot.com/docs/mongoUtils/mongoUtils.importsExports.html):
and you can install the library with `pip install mongoUtils

- you will need to also install xldr library
- disclaimer: I am the author of this library

Comment: drop_collection=True crashes the programme, therefore it's not usable if you don't want to drop your collection every time, but need to update it

Comment: @nickmilon - Hey! I could not get mongoUtils(v1.1.8) to work at all. I get: AttributeError: module 'mongoUtils' has no attribute 'import_workbook'.  
Anyone else tried this library?

Answer (score 1):

In case the DB server is not local, You will have to specify the host, port, username, password along with the DB name, collection name.

```
mongoimport --host <hostname>:<port> --username <username> --password <password> --db <db name> --collection <collection name> --type csv --headerline --file /path/to/myfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle loading the Excel file content by writing Java code using Apache POI library (https://poi.apache.org/). The library is developed for working with MS office application data including Excel.

I have recently created the application based on the technology that will help you to load Excel files to the MongoDB database.

The application is available under  http://www.abespalov.com/ and tested only for Windows, but should work for Linux as well. The application will create necessary collection automatically and populate the collection with the Excel file content. You can export several files in parallel. You can skip the step to convert the files into the CSV format. The application handles the xls and xlsx formats.

Overall application stages are :

**1)** Load the excel file content. Here is the code depending on file extension:

```
fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inputSheetFile.getName());

if (fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
        workbook = createWorkbook(openOPCPackage(inputSheetFile));
} else {
        workbook = createWorkbook(openNPOIFSFileSystemPackage(inputSheetFile));
}

sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

**2)** Establish the MongoDB connection. I use the MongoClientURI library;

```
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(
                    "mongodb://" + dbUser + ":" + dbPassword + "@" + dbServer 
+ ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbDatabase);
            excel2db.mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
```

**3)** Iterate over the sheet and inset rows into the collection. Here is a piece of Java code :

```
Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();

    //get column names from a header
    short minColIdx = row.getFirstCellNum();
    short maxColIdx = row.getLastCellNum();

    ArrayList<String> columnNameList = new ArrayList();
    String columnName;

    logger.info("The table {} is being populated", tableName);

    //populate a list of column names
    for (short colIdx = minColIdx; colIdx < maxColIdx; colIdx = (short) (colIdx + 1)) {
        columnNameList.add(row.getCell(colIdx) == null? "": row.getCell(colIdx).toString());
    }

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

        Document document = new Document();
        Row rowData = (Row) rowIterator.next();

        numOfProcessedRows++;
        for (short colIdx = minColIdx; colIdx < maxColIdx; colIdx = (short) (colIdx + 1)) {
            document.put(columnNameList.get(colIdx), rowData.getCell(colIdx).toString());
        }

        //save the document into a collection, point to the database
        MongoCollection mongoCollection = mongoDB.getCollection(tableName);
        mongoCollection.insertOne(document);

    }
}
```

Here you can find all Java code for the application created for exporting excel to Postgres (https://github.com/palych-piter/Excel2DB).